# Use Mail app for mailto links but not receive?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, gmail

I use the Outlook email app but because Apple doesn't allow changing associated apps for things like mailto links, whenever I click on "Send feedback" in an app or an email address on a website, I'm presented with "Please configure an email account".

Is there any way to configure the Mail app for send only? I don't want to have two copies of my inbox. (This is for a GMail account)

**CLARIFICATION - This is on an iPhone not a Mac**

Comment: I wonder if you can configure mail, and then delete the imap server but keep the smtp server. Just a wild guess.

Comment: As it stands, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Vitalydotn I tried looking for that setting but couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to configure your default Mailer.
It installs as a Control Panel.

[image]

Comment: Sorry this is on an iPhone not a Mac. I've revised my initial question.